# pika Context Manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to write a context manager to connect to rabbit using `pika`. This is how it looks

```
import pika
 
 
class RabbitConnection:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, queue_name, port=5627):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.port = port
        self.queue_name = queue_name
 
    def __enter__(self):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.user, self.password)
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=self.host,
            port=self.port,
            credentials=credentials
        )
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name)
        return self.channel
 
    def __exit__(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

But it doesn't work. Here is simple django view for sending message to rabbit

```
def send_message(request):
    message = request.GET['message']
    queue_name = 'hello'
    with RabbitConnection(settings.RABBIT_HOST, settings.RABBIT_USER, settings.RABBIT_PASSWORD, queue_name) as rc:
        rc.basic_publish(
            exchange='',
            routing_key=queue_name,
            body=message,
        )
    return HttpResponse()
```

But I got an error `pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError` on line `self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)`

The funny thing is when I use same code without context manager it works (no errors)

```
def send_message(request):
    message = request.GET['message']
    queue_name = 'hello'
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(settings.RABBIT_USER, settings.RABBIT_PASSWORD)
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=settings.RABBIT_HOST,
        port=5672,
        credentials=credentials
    )
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange='',
        routing_key='hello',
        body=message,
    )
    connection.close()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Where the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at the default port you're using:

```
def __init__(self, host, user, password, queue_name, port=5627):
```

The rabbitmq port is typically 5672...